# Install prebuilt third-party binary via Makefile.am

Tags: autotools, automake

I'm using the autotools and I have a prebuilt binary that I want to install along with all the other stuff that is built from source.
I tried to include it in my Makefile.am with

```
libexec_PROGRAMS = thirdparty/feever
```

The problem here is that it always wants to compile the file thirdparty/feever.c - which does not exist.
I also have other files that shall be installed in the same way, so I'd prefer a clean solution. What's the standard way to do that? I'm stuck, although I'm sure there must be a simple trick ... :-)
I already tried using the _DATA primary, but it doesn't set the exec flag, which I need.

Peter

Answer (score 2):

This sounds really counter-intuitive, but have you tried installing it as a script?

```
libexec_SCRIPTS = thirdparty/feever
```

Comment: This is how I do it. In addition, this means it won't delete the binary when you run `make clean`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `install-exec-local`:

```
install-exec-local:
    @$(NORMAL_INSTALL)
    $(INSTALL_PROGRAM) -m 755 thirdparty/feever "$(DESTDIR)$(libexecdir)"
```